# Kafka MirrorMaker 2 - Rename Topic AND retain consumer offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am looking to rename a large amount of topics (so we can create a virtual namespace for a second environment) i.e. production_topic1/development_topic1 etc.. However I also need to retain the consumer offsets used by Standard consumers, producers as well as kafka Streams. I know both operations are possible with Mirror Maker, but are they both possible at the same time?

Comment: What issues are you having? Yes, MM2 can sync consumer offsets. Producers and "Kafka Streams" don't have separate offsets, unclear what you mean by that

Comment: Sorry - what I mean is, I plan to migrate the offsets _and_ change the topic names. Is that likely to corrupt the migrated offsets?

Comment: You can add a prefix/suffix to mirrored topics. This is a well documented pattern, but I don't think you can wholly rename them (e.g. replace substring production with development). Consumer groups are tied to topic names, though, yes. There's no issue from producer side because those applications are hard coded to send to specific topics, and same for Kafka Streams outgoing records